# Seam still visible when close to object

Tags: texturing

I used texture paint to create a seamless texture for my object with the clone brush, but the seams are still visible when the camera is really close to them. I'm wondering if this is inevitable or fixable.

Also, I created the displacement map for it with Photoshop's 3D feature. When using it in Blender, when I increase the strength too much in the bump node, it makes the seams become very visible, even from a distance (that's not the case in the image). Am I creating and applying the displacement map correctly or is there a more efficient way?
[image]

Comment: maybe try to remove the seam with the Clone brush? Also increase the brush Bleed option a bit?

Comment: I did it and it's still visible when close.

Comment: if L0Lock's answer is not good, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/052a8c2ce6ae4451936b95bc5679f7e5

Comment: I had to create a new blender file, because the original has alot of objects.

Comment: you need to pack your image before saving: File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend, please share again

Comment: I had to reduce the textures from 8K to 1K. The seams are even more visible now: https://pasteall.org/blend/9d4586c241ab42e6b374a7a640f87437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like it's due to bad normal map but it's hard to guess how it happened, if you baked this normal map it must have happened at this moment, but we can't do anything as we don't have the original object.

Anyway what you can do from now is enable the *Node Wrangler* addon, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> left click on the *Grip 05 Normal 01 8K* *Image Texture* node in order to view the normal map only. In the 3D view switch to *Texture Paint* mode, select the *Clone brush* in the Tool panel on the left, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> left click to point on an area that you want to duplicate, and begin to paint on the limit line, it will remove the bad connection.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your nodetree, it looks like you set your image texture nodes' Extension to Repeat.

I might be wrong on this but if I remember well, Image Texture nodes use UV mapping when nothing feeds their vercor input, and changing the Extend option will change the texture mapping. If yes, then that might be the source of the issue:
While the image texture may be seamless when repeated, the UVs will always display a break at their seams. That's why when using UVs, you either paint a texture adapted to the UVs and project it as is, or you use a seamless texture but map it using generated mapping.

Also, any texture that isn't plugged into Base Color or Subsurface Color (which are conveniently socketed in yellow) should have their Color Space set to non-color.